# Angular ng-repeat rendering issue for small lidt

Tags: angularjs

I have the 2 of objects below:

```
$scope.MyObj_1={
    Id:"1",
    Title:"Title1",
    Items:[
        {
            Id:"1",
            Comment:"Simple comment 1",
        }
    ]
};

$scope.MyObj_2={
    Id:"2",
    Title:"Title1",
    Items:[
        {
            Id:"2",
            Comment:"Simple comment 2",
        },
        {
            Id:"3",
            Comment:"Simple comment 3",
        },
        {
            Id:"4",
            Comment:"Simple comment 4",
        }
    ]
};
```

And I have this html template (just to simplify):

`<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="note in MyObj.Items" >{{item.Comment}}</li>
</ul>`

When I set MyObj with MyObj_1 value and then I set MyObj with MyObj_2 I am getting rendering problem related to the slowness of ng-repeat. In fact ng-repeat starts by adding items of MyObj_2 and then removes the item related to MyObj_1.

I tried ng-cloak and $timeout but the behavior still the same.

I am wondering why ng-repeat did not remove old element first and then push new elements.

Comment: could you please show how you are assigning the values to $scope.MyObj ?

Comment: Here is how I am assigning values: $scope.MyObj = angular.copy($scope.MyObj_2);

Answer (score 0):

Angular.copy makes clone of object from source to destination.It deletes all objects from destination object and then copy properties from source.

Angular.merge appends the source object to destination.If destination object already has elements, it will remain there and new properties from source object will add to destination object.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is expected if you set the `$scope.MyObj_2 = $scope.MyObj_1;`
Then they will point to the same reference in memory.

What you need to use is [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) which creates a deep copy of source like this

```
$scope.MyObj_2 = angular.copy($scope.MyObj_1);
```

Also, in the repeat you have a typeo, should be

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="note in MyObj.Items" >{{note.Comment}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It was just a typo. my problem is on rendering. As you can see in MyObj_1 I have only 1 item and in MyObj_2 I have 3 Items. So here is the scenraio: When I assign first MyObj = MyObj_1 and later I make MyObj = MyObj_2 I see in my list 4 items and then the first one is removed, so it remains 3 as expected. So my question is how to get rid of this behavior? it is a kind of animation that I cannot get rid of.

Comment: It is confusing for end users. The only way that worked for me is that I assign an empty array: MyObj.Items = [];  later I use $timeout(function(){ MyObj = MyObj_2},1000, true); But 1000 is huge for the end users to switch between assignment.

Comment: @user3325246 If you use $timeout, your code will always render after the call stack is empty. This means that it can look like an animation because angular will render the array sat in the scope and then when the $timeout callbacks kicks in a new value will be added to the array which makes the UI render two times..

Comment: I reproduced the same behavior with the filter. I tried also the "track by" but I am getting always the same behavior. It seems that there is an issue with my template, because when I used a SIMPLE template (just <li/> elements) I did not get the issue. So how can improve the rendering processing?

Comment: Finally, as I was wondering, it was due to CSS class for list. When removing the old behavior is gone.